# I cannot use yum command and ssh after mount drive.(CentOS)

Tags: ssh, centos, mount, yum, command-not-found

I cannot use yum command after I mount like below.

```
mount /dev/xvdb3 /usr

Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda                          9.9G  1.9G  7.6G  20% /
none                               3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdb1                        1012M   34M  927M   4% /tmp
/dev/xvdb2                          20G  250M   19G   2% /var
/dev/xvdb3                          15G  1.5G   13G  11% /usr
/dev/mapper/instancevg-instancelv  792G  197M  751G   1% /home

[root@ip-10-0-0-10 ~]# yum
-bash: yum: command not found
```

I can use yum after I umount /dev/xvdb3.
ssh cannot connect remotely after disconnected from the server.
I MUST REBOOT server to connect by ssh.
What should I do?

Comment: I believe there is additional info that's missing from this Q that's stalling any of us from being able to help you further. For example this system is not an actual physical host with CentOS on it, correct? It's a virtual machine (I'm assuming it's using XEN), can you confirm this? Also a simple `ls -l /usr/bin/yum` should reveal if `yum` is installed or not, it many not be working because of other reasons but please do confirm this too.

Comment: I'm using amazon ec2 instance store AMI

Comment: Why are you mounting these partitions w/ that instance? Is this something you'd normally be doing w/ it or are you doing something else with?

Comment: For ec2 m1.large instance got 2 hardisk with 420gb…I make 1st hardisk into 4 partition and mount 3 partition into /tmp /usr /var…another partition comboine with 2nd hardisk and mount into /home…this is what I want to do for the pre-installation of DirectAdmin…

Answer (score 0):

If you do `which yum`, you will probably get `/usr/bin/yum` as an answer.

If you mount `/dev/xvdb3` on `/usr` all the files under "the old" `/usr` are hidden. Unless in the root of `/dev/xvdb3` there exists a `bin` directory which contains the `yum` executable, your `bash` shell will not find it.

If there are other `yum` executables around, you could try `hash -r` which make `bash` do a search for `yum` instead of trying to find it from the old place it now where to get it from.

---

The above explains why `yum` stops working. As you write in your comment you need more space on `/` you can do one of the following:

1. Move all of the data to the partition `/dev/xvdb3` and mount that partition as `/usr`
2. Mount `/dev/xvdb3` some where else (`/mnt/usr`), move some of the material from `/usr` to `/mnt/usr` and create a link in the original location.
3. Ask the (commercial) support of DirectAdmin how to install the packages somewhere else (e.g. `/opt/DirectAdmin` ) and mount the `/dev/xvdb3` there.

The first of those might be hindered by files being accessed under `/usr` making it difficult to move them.

Since `/` and `/tmp` are different partitions, there is no way to mount `/usr` somewhere else to get free space on both, for that you would have to unmount `/tmp` after moving away the data in `/usr`.

I recommend to try option 3 first to get this (or any other commercial) software installed.

Comment: not also affect the yum command. I cannot connect to server (refuse by server) after I  disconnected from the server.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. What is the output from `which yum` at the time you can use it?

Comment: <<<<<-bash: /usr/bin/which: No such file or directory>>>>>this is the output of "which yum" and "which ssh"

Comment: And this is at the time you can use `yum` as requested? Unmount the drive and try again.

Comment: work normal after unmount. For ssh, after disconnected from the server, I cannot reconnect to server. I need to reboot my server to connect the server by ssh. This is the problem.

Comment: Why don't you do `sudo mdkir /mnt/usr; sudo mount /dev/xvdb3 /mnt/usr` and access the drive under `/usr2`?

Comment: I need to install DirectAdmin and mount more disk space into /usr /var /tmp /home…is that mount to /mnt/usr work?This question sound stupid because I am a newbie of linux…